# Which is the best way to develop an R package that needs a heavy C++ library?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am trying to develop an *R package* that uses some C++ code employing `Rcpp`. In my C++ code, I use a C++ library encoded in a header `.hpp` that I have put in `inst/miscell` as is recommended with the line

```
PKG_CXXFLAGS = -I../inst/miscell
```

in *Makevars* and *Makevars.win*, but when I compile the package I get a note adverting me that:

```
checking installed package size ... NOTE
installed size is 39.4Mb
```

Is there any possibility to not include the header file in the code and take it from GitHub or wherever at the compilation of the package?

And if is possible, Which is the best way to do that?

Comment: There are _many_ possible solutions and none of it leads itself to a one sentence answer. Eg my [BH](https://cran.r-project.org/package=BH) package is still way bigger. Maybe come to the rcpp-devel list for a broader discussion.  But in short: as of today, 1408 packages on CRAN use Rcpp and many of these do what you aim to do in _some_ way.  You can study these and see what best fits your needs.  There are multiple tradeoffs to consider.